# Does ros 2.0 yet exist? If so where can I find it

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read some descriptions about a potential ROS 2.0.

Does it yet exist?

If so where can I find it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220716/does-ros-2.0-yet-exist?-if-so-where-can-i-find-it/) by [Nolan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25058/nolan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS2 is still under development. You can find documentation and alpha releases here:

https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2